# Facebook pixel: fbevents.js cause error "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Tags: facebook-events, facebook-pixel

When I click certain elements on the page it throws this error [image]

[image]

Can anyone explain why is it happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When initializing:

```
fbq('init', "your_app_id");
```

`your_app_id` must be string

Comment: I've been passing an integer for ages. Thank you!